# why is my component not functioning properly with a screen reader

Tags: reactjs, combobox, accessibility, dropdown

I have created a dynamic drop down component using the select and options pattern. Currently when using a screen reader the behavior is as follows:
when navigating to it I get the correct information:
"this field is required {label} combobox 1 of 4" (seemingly telling me the default selected one which is in place 1 of 4)

However when I arrow through the options it does not read off what they are. After selecting the option I want it then announces it for example:
"Apple 3 of 4"

I am in need of it announcing as the user keyboards through the options.

The code is as follows for the entire component:

```
import { GenericControlProps } from "..";

import "./HighgearDropdown.scss";

export interface Option {
  label: string;
  value: string;
}

export interface OptionGroup {
  title: string;
  options: Option[];
}

export type HighgearDropdownProps = GenericControlProps<string> & {
  options: (Option | OptionGroup)[];
};

export const HighgearDropdown: React.FC<HighgearDropdownProps> = (props) => {
  // This is state so that we continue showing the empty option after the initial render.
  const [showEmptyOption] = React.useState(!props.value);

  const { id, value = "", focusRef, disabled, onChange, options } = props;

  return (
    <select
      ref={focusRef as React.Ref<HTMLSelectElement>}
      className="hg-control-dropdown"
      onChange={(ev) => onChange(ev.currentTarget.value)}
      {...{ id, value, disabled }}
    >
      {showEmptyOption && <option value="" />}
      {options.map((it, i) => {
        return "title" in it ? (
          <optgroup key={i} label={it.title}>
            {it.options.map((jt, j) => (
              <option key={j} value={jt.value}>
                {jt.label}
              </option>
            ))}
          </optgroup>
        ) : (
          <option key={i} value={it.value}>
            {it.label}
          </option>
        );
      })}
    </select>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is **example 3** similar to what you want?  https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/combobox/aria1.1pattern/listbox-combo.html#ex3_label

Comment: unfortunately no, not really. 
This is a for a dynamic rendered form. So A user will load a form it will have properties attached to it. The drop down itself is a select with option inside that are provided by the form. 
So what is happening is the component receives an id some options and some values. Those values are being loaded and working fine however and when selected they are announced. However in up down nav they are not announced pre-selection.

Comment: Ignoring where the data comes from, are the underlying html elements similar?